# How do I simplify ⋂{ ⌀, ⌀, ⌀, ⌀}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. I know how to get the intersection of two sets but I don't know what to do with this kind of notation.

Comment: It must be the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_intersections) of the four sets enclosed into braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cap$ can be recognized as the notation of an operator on non-empty sets characterized by:$$x\in\cap a\iff\forall b\in a\;x\in b$$

In that context the common expression  $A\cap B$ can be looked at as an abbreviation of $\cap\{A,B\}$ and $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ as an abbreviation of $\cap\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$.

So the set in the title of your question is the same as:$$\varnothing\cap\wp\varnothing\cap\wp\wp\varnothing\cap\wp\wp\wp\varnothing$$
where $\wp(A):=\{B\mid B\subseteq A\}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a bunch, that's all I needed to understand this

Comment: You are very welcome.